# Count data distribution

Tags: poisson-distribution

I am currently dealing with count data with $n=360$.

The data fits neither the Poisson nor the negative binomial distribution. 
Additionally, I don't think my data has excess zeroes, so there is no point of considering zero-inflated model.

Now I am considering an alternative model (COM Poisson). 
What else do you suggest?

Comment: Please show the distribution. How many 0's, 1's etc.?

Comment: Without more information, how would we suggest anything? By "COM Poisson" do you mean 'compound Poisson'? If so, what is it about your situation that would suggest it? Which one (i.e. what is the mixing distribution)?

Answer (score 0):

[Conway-Maxwell Poisson](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway%E2%80%93Maxwell%E2%80%93Poisson_distribution), which is basically a flexible generalisation of the Poisson to allow for over or under dispersion, sounds very appropriate and I wouldn't worry about other alternatives until you had found that there were problems.

Depending on your research question you might not need to model its family specifically at all but could do inference using quasi likelihood based on just modelling the first two moments; but we'd need to know a lot more about your situation to advise on that as an option.